# Docker, postgres. Port is already allocated

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker

I have some problems with build my project by docker. Screen of my error is below . [image] What I have to change or which work have I stop to resolve this problems. Help pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figure out which process on the host is using that port, and stop/change it

```
sudo netstat -nap --tcp | grep LISTEN
```

Or change the published port in docker, aka

```
docker run -p 5430:5432 postgres
```

Comment: Ohhh this is windows.   Not sure of the appropriate netstat equivalent.

Comment: Yes, this is windows. When I stop postgres in services docker-compose works fine. But in future I will have a database and I have to run this...

Comment: One of them will have to change ports.

Comment: thanks, how can I change ports to first state,if I will crash project..?